# Drag and Drop issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

I am developing an iPhone app. in that app i have some images in scroll view. the requirement is drag and drop those images to a view and vice-verse. i am able to do drag image from scroll view and drop it in self.view. but when i am trying it reverse mean drag those image from self.view and drop it to scroll view it create problem for me.i am using gesture.so i want it will be done by gesture.

This is my code .

y=0;

```
for (int i=0; i<tileImgArray.count; i++)
{
    imgScroll=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgScroll=[[dragImages objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Image"];
    imgScroll.frame=CGRectMake(5, y, 40, 30);
    imgScroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [srlPuzzlePieces addSubview:imgScroll];
    y=y+50;
}


NSMutableArray *draggableSubjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dragImages];
NSMutableArray *droppableAreas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:play_view, nil];
_dragDropManager = [[DragDropManager alloc] initWithDragSubjects:draggableSubjects andDropAreas:droppableAreas];
_dragDropManager.dragImages=dragImages;
[draggableSubjects release];
[droppableAreas release];
[dragImages release];

panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:_dragDropManager action:@selector(dragging:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];

srlPuzzlePieces.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0,y);
```

and below are my drag and drop file logic

[Drag and drop files logic](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bn5424fcpo3gh2t/ZmEbvaSNuW)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U can refer https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView for dragging and dropping.